# Wordpress Shortcode Display Issue

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, display

I want't so show all wordpress categories on a page by using a shortcode.

My code:

```
function catpage_function(){
$variable = wp_list_categories( array(
     'show_count'         => true,
     'orderby'             => 'name',
     'style'               => 'none',
     'hide_empty'         => 0
   ) );
   return $variable; 
}
add_shortcode('catpage', 'catpage_function' );
```

But when i insert the shortcode [catpage] to the page, it wasn't displayed under the heading. the code is shown above the heading.

[Screenshot of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkhS9.png)

What could i do?

Comment: on shortcode function `catpage_function` you should return string not `$variable`

Comment: What did you exactly mean?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the ob_start() to render the HTML in shortcode correctly

```
<?php 
function catpage_function(){
    ob_start();
    $variable = wp_list_categories( array(
        'show_count'         => true,
         'orderby'             => 'name',
          'style'               => 'none',
          'hide_empty'         => 0,
          'echo'                => 0,
    ) );
    ob_end_clean();   
    return $variable; 
}
add_shortcode('catpage', 'catpage_function' );
```

Answer (score 0):

on shortcode function `catpage_function` you should return string (set `echo` to `false`):

```
function catpage_function(){
   $variable = wp_list_categories( array(
     'show_count'         => true,
     'orderby'             => 'name',
     'style'               => 'none',
     'hide_empty'         => 0,
     'echo'                => 0,
   ) );
   return $variable; 
}
add_shortcode('catpage', 'catpage_function' );
```